# How checkEditId() method protect from direct edit a record

Tags: joomla-3.x, model

**checkEditId() is very very useful fore security purpose as it protect our edit form from direct access.**
but i don't know how it is implemented i check the edit() function of JModelAdmin and also check save() but did not found how it is implemented.?

Comment: Here is a Github issue related to the use of that function in Joomla: https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/9013

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see it in action in the main controllers of the core components. For example [ContentController](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/components/com_content/controller.php#L98) of Content component.

```
// Check for edit form.
if ($vName == 'form' && !$this->checkEditId('com_content.edit.article', $id))
{
    // Somehow the person just went to the form - we don't allow that.
    return JError::raiseError(403, JText::sprintf('JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_UNHELD_ID', $id));
}
```